# Rails hidden field in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a `has_many, through:` relationship in my Rails application.

#### Groups Model

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :usergroups
  has_many :users, through: :usergroups
end
```

#### User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups, through: :usergroups
end
```

#### Usergroups Model

```
class Usergroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

In my route `http://localhost:3000/usergroups/new` I have this form.

```
<%= form_with(model: usergroup, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :user_id, id: 'user', data: { autocomplete_source: User.order(:email).map(&:email) } %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :group_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :group_id, id: 'group', data: { autocomplete_source: Group.order(:group_name).map(&:group_name) } %>
  </div>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I am using jQuery autocomplete to search for these fields with the data attribute being whatever the user is entering into the `User` and `Group` field.

Since I need the `user_id` and the `group_id` to be able to add these users I am running into an issue because it is populating the `user_email` and `group_name` instead of the `user_id` and `group_id`. How can I add these users with the email and group name or add a hidden field with the id based on the `group_name` and `user_email` they add?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of the selected option using `select` event listener for each combo box, but before that, you need to get the id of group and email:

**Form:**

```
// Update the 'data' attribute for both text fields, so you will get the id and value:
<%= form_with(model: usergroup, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :user_id, id: 'user', data: { autocomplete_source: User.order(:email).map{ |item| {id: item.id , value: item.email} } } %>

  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :group_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :group_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :group_id, id: 'group', data: { autocomplete_source: Group.order(:group_name).map{ |item| {id: item.id , value: item.group_name } } } %>

  </div>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//below events can be combined into one
$("#user").autocomplete({
      // suppose ui represents the returned value 
      select: function( event, ui ) {        
        $("#user").attr('data-selected-id', ui.item.id);
        // to set a hidden field
        $('[name="usergroup[user_id]"]').val(ui.item.id);
        console.log(ui.item);
        return false;
      }
    });

$("#group").autocomplete({
      // ui.item represents the returned object { id: # , value: ''} 
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        this.value = ui.item.value;        
        $("#group").attr('data-selected-id', ui.item.id);
        // to set a hidden field
        $('[name="usergroup[group_id]"]').val(ui.item.id);
        console.log(ui.item);
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: For some reason when I add these two it will not submit unless I add `optional: true` to both `belongs_to` in my usergroup model. When I add that and click submit I get this error. https://imgur.com/a/oIL1U - any idea why? It semes to think that the user_id is 0 when it is actually 1?

Comment: @TrentonTyler in the code I have posted I didn't set the user_id or group_id itself, I just set the `data-selected-id` attribute

Comment: @TrentonTyler I have updated my answer to include the setting of hidden fields, try now

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CffYm - New SC shows that its showing up as no id for both group and user.

Comment: @TrentonTyler the group id is not 0, anyway before submitting the form, check what is the value of user_id `$('#user_id').val()`

Comment: @TrentonTyler I have changed the order of hidden fields to be before the input fields.

Comment: When the fields are populated and I check the value of them before submitting the form. -- > https://imgur.com/a/Chfmq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162306/discussion-between-shiko-and-trenton-tyler).